# AWS Glue Crawler not able to fetch metdata from s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have some data in my s3 bucket, the data is in parquet format and compression type is snappy, when I am running the crawler on that files, crawler is successfully creating table but the table doesn't have any columns, it seems the crawler is not able to fetch the metadata from the path, I saw the files are KMS encrypted in my s3 bucket so that's why crawler is not able to take the columns, can anyone suggest any work around for this like how can we access those encrypted data from glue crawler?

Comment: By granting the glue crawler the relevant KMS permissions.

Comment: If it SSE-S3 encryption then you will not require any permission. and if it KMS CMK then add and run crawler.

Comment: Thanks @Nikk , so i will have to add the kms permission to the respective bucket?

Comment: No, you need to configure the IAM role the crawler uses https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/define-crawler.html *"The crawler assumes this role. It must have permissions similar to the AWS managed policy AWSGlueServiceRole. For Amazon S3 and DynamoDB sources, it must also have permissions to access the data store. If the crawler reads Amazon S3 data encrypted with AWS Key Management Service (AWS KMS), then the role must have decrypt permissions on the AWS KMS key."*